# How should I code this function to rotate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I have a function:

```
    function headerNudge(elem, rot, dur) {
        elem.rotate({ 
        bind: { 
            mouseover : function() { 
                $(this).rotate({
                    animateTo:rot,
                    duration:dur,
            callback: function(){
                $(this).rotate({
                            animateTo:-rot,
                            duration:dur,
                    callback: function(){
                        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:0,duration:dur })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
      }
        }      
        });         
    }
```

Basically it just uses the [jQueryRotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) plugin to nudge an image on mouseover to one slide and then another, to give the effect of a shake.

I can see my code looks absolutely horrible, (I come from a php/c# background) can anoyone suggest a better means to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Could you make use of [CSS Transitions](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/)?

Comment: well this pluggin already works and functions well on all platforms including old versions of ie, so i don't want to change the pluggin, just the syntax of my code to make it cleaner